# Why does "ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls)" fails within Revit API 2019?

Tags: revit-api, pyrevit

I am trying to filter walls. For that I use

```
categories = List[ElementId]()
myId = ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls)
categories.Add(myId)
```

..but this obviously doesn't return a valid ElementId, as when I print it, it has some negative value (and if I print "doc.GetElement(myId)", I get "None").

Then, indeed when creating the filter...

```
filter = ParameterFilterElement.Create(doc, "Walls filter", categories)
```

...I get an ArgumentException.
I'm using Revit 2019 (with pyRevit). As far as I remember, it used to work with Revit 2018, but I don't see any reason it shouldn't anymore. What am I missing?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the [filtered element collector `OfCategory` Method](https://apidocs.co/apps/revit/2019/c3523c35-4a07-9723-3c28-de3cc47b2ad0.htm).

E.g., check out The Building Coder hints on [filtered element collector optimisation](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2018/06/forge-tutorials-and-filtering-for-a-parameter-value.html#4).

Comment: Still, I don't understand: Doing "a = ElementId(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls)" yields a negative Id, something like -2000011, although this exact same command is used in the examples found on ApiDocs.co for ParameterFilterElement. Does a negative Id mean that it isn't a valid element? Because indeed trying then something like "doc.GetElement(a)" yields None. Why isn't this working? Thanks!

Comment: in the Revit API, a negative element id is usually a built-in constant enumeration value. in this case, it is a BuiltInCategory enumeration value. you can look at it in the Visual Studio debugger and in the help file. non-built-in element ids are normally positive and sequential.

Answer (score 0):

Apply an ElementCategoryFilter to the collector to get all the walls of the project. By using the following code you can filter any kind of category. I have tried this on Revit 2019.

```
FilteredElementCollector collector = new FilteredElementCollector(document);
ICollection<Element> walls = collector.OfCategory(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls).ToElements();
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Mah Noor answer.

If you need to have a filter with multiple categories, you can use:

```
        ElementCategoryFilter wallFilter = new ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_Walls);
        ElementCategoryFilter windowFilter = new ElementCategoryFilter(BuiltInCategory.OST_Windows);
        LogicalOrFilter wallAndWindowFilter = new LogicalOrFilter(wallFilter, windowFilter);
        ICollection<Element> collection = new FilteredElementCollector(doc).WherePasses(wallAndWindowFilter);
```

Bonus tip, you may want to add .WhereElementIsNotElementType() or .WhereElementIsElementType() to your query.

Best regards

François